# Android, Adding window failed when PopupMenu.show()

Tags: android, crash, popupmenu

I add a menu in my WebView Activity. App will crash sometimes when the PopupMenu.show() executed.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:536)  at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:260)
>     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1019)    at
>   android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:925)   at
>   android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:629)     at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:148)
>     at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:113)
>     at android.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:167)    at
>   com.lukouapp.app.ui.base.LKWebActivity.showMenu(LKWebActivity.java:275)
>     at
>   com.lukouapp.app.ui.base.LKWebActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(LKWebActivity.java:316)
>     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2618)  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:350)

Comment: no one ever cross this problem?

Comment: I am seeing it in my app but only on Android 4.4, mostly samsung phones and a large part on tablets.

Answer (score 1):

You could just simply add !isFinishing() check before showing the popup/alertDialog

here is the sample code for it

```
if(popup!=null&&!isFinishing()) {
    popup.show();
}
```